# Statistical significance with p-value and confidence interval

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

A matched pairs design was used to compare test scores in a statistics course.  Twenty-four students were chosen randomly from a large class.  For each chosen student, their test 1 and test 2 scores were recorded.  A 95% confidence interval for the difference in test scores was constructed, along with the corresponding 2-sided p-value was given as 
$[-0.70, 10.45]$, and the 2-sided p-value $= 0.084$.

How does one determine whether or not this result is statistically significant at the 5% level of significance?

Also, if a $90%$ confidence interval was constructed instead of a 95% one, would it contain $0$?

Would appreciate some clues.

Answer (score 1):

1) For testing $H_0: \delta = 0$ vs. $H_a: \delta \ne 0,$ where the population
difference in test 1 and test 2 scores is $\mu_1 - \mu_2 = \delta,$
one does not reject $H_0$ at level 5% if the two-sided P-value exceeds 5%.
Because your P-value is $0.084 > 0.05$ you do not reject.

2) Another criterion for failing to reject in (1) is that the 95% 
confidence interval (CI) contains $0.$ The CI can be considered 
an interval of 'acceptable' values of $\delta.$

3) The 95% CI in (2) is of the form $\bar D \pm t^*s_D/\sqrt{n};$
where $\bar D$ is the sample mean of the observed differences $D_i = X_i - Y_i,$
where $X_i$ and $Y_i$ the $i$th students difference in test 1 and test 2 scores;
$s_D$ is the the sample standard deviation of the $D_i$; $n = 24;$ and
$t^* = 2.069$ cuts 2.5% of the probability from the upper tail of Student's t
distribution with $n - 1 = 23$ degrees of freedom.

For the same data, a 90% CI would be the same, except that you would use
$t^* = 1.714,$ which cuts 5% of the probability from the upper tail of the same
distribution. I will leave it to you to determine what difference the
change from  $t^* = 2.069$ to  $t^* = 1.714$ would make in the width of the CI.

*Note:* You should look at printed tables of t distributions (or use software) to verify the values of $t^*$ quoted above.

Comment: Can you please clarify: you say that the 90% CI would be the same, yet you say that the new $t^*$ will have an effect on its width? Sorry, I'm somewhat confused.

Comment: I said "... the same, **except that** ...." Maybe it would have been clearer if I had said " ... of the same form, and ...." In any case, I hope you can take if from there.

Comment: I would take it from there if I knew how exactly the value of $t^*$ participates in the construction of a confidence interval.

Comment: Maybe look at it this way. The quantity $2.069\,s_D/\sqrt{24},$ called the 'margin of error' is half the width of the 95% CI. Pick it apart. With a little thought, I bet you can work out the value of $s_D$ and then maybe finish the problem, while I go eat some chocolate ice cream.

Comment: So $s_D \approx 13.2$, thus $1.714 \cdot 13.2/\sqrt{24}\approx 4.62$ is the width of the 90% CI. So it is much narrower then, and if it is centred about the same point then $0$ will not be contained. Am I correct? Bon appetit!